# Windows batch: Remove lines from a merged file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am currently making a batch file that merges both, the output from systeminfo, and ipconfig:

```
@ECHO OFF
pause
systeminfo > "%computername% SystemInfo.txt"
ipconfig >> "%computername% SystemInfo.txt"
"%computername% systeminfo.txt"
```

The code runs fine and nicely, also independently from OS version and OS language as far as I can tell. My problem though, lies with the systeminfo dump. It lists all 100+ hotfixes that have ever been installed in the machine that is runs on, making the txt file barely legible:

```
<useful info>
[01]: File 1
[02]: File 1
[03]: File 1
[04]: File 1
....
[150]: file 1
etc...
<useful info>
```

There's also another problem, namely that this batch file has to run on computers that either run Dutch windows or English windows, meaning that I can't filter on words, because those hotfixes and the words will be different on every computer. Anybody have a nice sollution to this problem.

Note: I have seen it solved the other way around, leaving only the relevant info using findstr. But, because that depends on the language, it is not a viable option.

Edit: The hotfixes are named differently on different OS'es as well, meaning that I can't filter on those. Example: on the XP SP3 I tested, most of the list will be compromised of hotfixes called "[##]file1" on vista however, you will see hex values in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

My original answer did not work, but I have another idea that works as long as the number and order of each systeminfo header is consistent. I am relying on the fact that the Hotfix(s): is always the 31st header.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
>systemInfo.txt (
  set cnt=0
  for /f "delims=" %%A in ('systeminfo') do (
    set "ln=%%A"
    if "!ln:~0,1!"==" " (if !cnt! neq 31 echo !ln!) else (
      echo !ln!
      set /a cnt+=1
    )
  )
  ipconfig
)
```

If the number and/or order of the headers can change, then I don't see how there can be a solution, other then to bite the bullet and look for the specific header text, accounting for all languages that you need to support.

**Original failed answer**

I don't know how reliable this is. It works for me on my machine, but it would not surprise me if on some machines it strips things it shouldn't.

```
>systemInfo.txt (
  systeminfo|findstr /vxrc:"                           \[[0-9]*\]: [^ ]*"
  ipconfig
)
```

All my hotfixes begin with KB, followed by a string of numbers. If this is always true, then the above could be improved as:

```
>systemInfo.txt (
  systeminfo|findstr /vxrc:"                           \[[0-9]*\]: KB[0-9]*"
  ipconfig
)
```

Comment: I get what you're coming from, but all hotfixes being called KB#### sadly isn't the case... The example provided was taken from the text that was generated by the script, it literally said "[#] file1". It also seems that vista will list the hex values of the hotfixes, further complicating the matter. The problem is that the search terms are different on each pc, be it OS, or OS language.

Comment: @shadowmanwkp - I'm not surprised my first answer didn't work. I've got one more idea. See my updated answer.

Comment: And that one seems to be the charm :D It appears that the information that comes before that always maintains the same amount of lines, from what I tested this solution should work flawlessly on a lot of pc's. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to figure it out, but you could format it based on the csv output from systeminfo.

```
systeminfo /fo csv > info.csv
```

The output, for any language will basically be:

```
(headers)"<col>", "<col>", "<col>" <...> "<col>"<newline>
(data)"<col>", "<col>", "<col>" <...> "<col>"
```

The hotfix column is the second to last column. so you could split it by quotes, and ignore that field. It'll have a bunch of crap in it, but it will still be `"hotfix, hotfix, hotfix,"` so you can just remove the whole thing in quotes.

String manipulation in batch is awful if you ask me. If this were me, I'd do it in a language with a string library and call that instead.